# What is the C interface to Lua for accessing a table's key/value pairs?

Tags: c, interface, lua, key-value, keyvaluepair

In Lua, using the **C** interface, given a table, how do I iterate through the table's key/value pairs?

Also, if some table table members are added using arrays, do I need a separate loop to iterate through those as well or is there a single way to iterate though those members at the same time as the key/value pairs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lua_next()` is just the same as Lua's `next()` function, which is used by the `pairs()` function.  It iterates all the members, both in the array part and the hash part.

If you want the analogue of `ipairs()`, the `lua_objlen()` gives you the same functionality as `#`.  Use it and `lua_rawgeti()` to numerically iterate over the array part.

Answer (score 11):

As Javier says, you want the [`lua_next()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next) function. I thought a code sample might help make things clearer since this can be a little tricky to use at first glance.

Quoting from the manual:

> A typical traversal looks like this:
>
> ```
> /* table is in the stack at index 't' */
> lua_pushnil(L);  /* first key */
> while (lua_next(L, t) != 0) {
>    /* uses 'key' (at index -2) and 'value' (at index -1) */
>    printf("%s - %s\n",
>           lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -2)),
>           lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1)));
>    /* removes 'value'; keeps 'key' for next iteration */
>    lua_pop(L, 1);
> }
> ```

Be aware that `lua_next()` is very sensitive to the key value left on the stack. **Do not** call `lua_tolstring()` on the key unless it really is already a string because that function will *replace* the value it converts.